# owl-carousel-o responsive option is not working Angular 7.2.9

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

customer-review.component.ts

```
customOptionsforslider = {
    loop: false,
    nav: true,
    dots: false,
    mouseDrag: true,
    touchDrag: true,
    pullDrag: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    margin: 30,
    smartSpeed: 500,
    autoplayTimeout: 1000,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
    navText: ['', ''],
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1.25,
      },
      576: {
        items: 2.25,
      },
      768: {
        items: 3,
      },
      1024: {
        items: 4,
      },
      1280: {
        items: 4,
      },
    },

  };
```

customer-review.component.html

```
<owl-carousel-o [options]="customOptionsforslider"></owl-carousel-o>
```

style.scss

```
@import '~ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/scss/owl.theme.default';
@import '~ngx-owl-carousel-o/lib/styles/scss/owl.carousel';
```

display slider with responsive device is not working
display slider only work < 768 device 
i have use owl-carousel-o because we need slider without jQuery